# Extract memo field data from dBase file

Tags: binaryfiles, dbase, clipper

I have a MSDOS clipper application that uses dBase as it's database engine, some of it's fields are stored on external files (with .BIN extension), the database file seems to store some binary pointer to that file (to link db rows with in-file information), anyone knows how can i extract the information on this files?

[On this capture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GNXQ2.png) you'll find the dBase file on the left, and the BIN file on the right.

The binary file has the following "header": JMS BIN

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try opening it with OpenOffice/LibreOffice Calc or Base.

Answer (score 0):

In dBase the memo fields are stored outside the table or .dbf files with a reference in the table.

Unless the clipper (compiled) application provides a way to read the memo fields it will be not possible to read the memo fields.

Alternatively if you have dBase or the clipper the DBU facility you can access the data in memo fields.